# Initialize enum value in runtime

Tags: swift, reflection, enums

Is it possible to initialize enum instance in runtime using name of the enum or type?

For example:

```
let enumName = "EnumName"
let E = StringToEnumType(enumName)
let res = E(rawValue: "some string value from enum")
```

Or at least is it possible to create enum instance using `dynamicType`?

Comment: I don't believe you can do that with the current reflection capabilities of Swift. What is the use case behind it?

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible in an elegant way, that means without returning `Any?` and needing to cast it.

Comment: @RMenke is it actually possible at all? Of course it would return `Any?` it couldn't possibly return `Any`. Could you post an answer with the solution? I couldn't figure out a way to do it.

Comment: @HugoTunius I want a function that returns `enum` value by passing `rawValue` and name or type of the enum

Comment: @RMenke I found some workaround. If you create an extension for enum with custom initializer then you will be able to instantiate it be dynamic type like `MyEnum.self.init(raw: value)`

Comment: @Moldaone Could you post an answer with how you ended up solving it?

Comment: @HugoTunius I didn't solve it. I am still looking for some solution that gives me that abstract functionality. Because adding to each enum custom init is a messy and extra code

Comment: @Moldaone still it would be useful if you update your question with your attempts. Then at least we can tell you if we tried that and found it a dead end, or tell you if you really are on to something.